# CakePHP SSL pages not found in Wamp VHost

Tags: php, cakephp, ssl, http-status-code-404, wampserver

I am trying to make my admin actions SSL protected, including the login and logout actions. But they are always not found, making a 404 error being the SSL working. When I try to access the login page, Cake redirects to https://cakeprebuild.dev/login, with the 404 error, the same happens with all the other admin actions.
Also, on my apache access log I have, on every entry related to these an "GET /login HTTP/1.1" 302 -, in this case for the login action. I am not sure if the issue is related to Cake or with some Wamp misconfiguration because this only happens when launching the project with a virtual host. If I try to run it using localhost, `https://localhost/CakePreBuild/login`, it works perfectly. How can this be fixed?

I am using CakePHP 2.4.4 and Wampserver 2.5 64bit

**UsersController**

```
public function beforeFilter() {
        parent::beforeFilter();
        $this->Auth->deny('index');
        if (isset($this->params['admin'])) {
            $this->Security->csrfCheck = false;
            $this->Security->blackHoleCallback = 'forceSSL';
            $this->Security->requireSecure();
        }
    }

public function forceSSL() {
    return $this->redirect('https://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $this->here);
}
```

Comment: Might help if you give details of whether it's redirecting, if it is where to...etc etc etc.